# How to List Properties Defined with Object.defineProperty

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to list all properties defined using Object.defineProperty?
These don't show up while iterating through the object:

```
for (var prop in obj) { ... }
```

And neither with Object.getOwnPropertyNames.

**Update:** I guess it is only possible if they are created with the enumerable: true flag set.

Comment: Non-enumerable properties **are** included in the array returned from `.getOwnPropertyNames()`.

Comment: Can you share more code? Particularly WRT `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Non-enumerable properties **are** returned by [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.getownpropertynames):

```js
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, "foo", {value:42});
document.body.innerHTML = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).join(", ");
```

If you define them with `Symbol` rather than string names, you'd use [`Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.getownpropertysymbols).

If you need to find non-enumerable **inherited** properties, you have to loop up your prototype chain via [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.getprototypeof).

Here's an example of finding all property names that are strings, regardless of whether they're enumerable, including inherited ones (note that we see the non-enumerables on `Object.prototype`; we could stop earlier if we didn't want them):

```js
var proto = {}
Object.defineProperty(proto, "answer", {value: 42});
var obj = Object.create(proto);
Object.defineProperty(obj, "question", {value: "Life, the Universe, and Everything"});

document.body.innerHTML = getAllPropertyNames(obj).join(", ");

function getAllPropertyNames(o) {
  var names = [];
  while (o) {     // We'd use `o != Object.prototype` to stop earlier
    names.push.apply(names, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o));
    o = Object.getPrototypeOf(o);
  }
  return names;
}
```

Comment: I absolutely swear I did not copy your opening sentence.

Comment: @Pointy: LOL!! I love it. Emphasis and everything.